# Magento still logging even after being told not to

Tags: magento

I have an issue with Magento still writing to the sql.txt file even after being told not to.

I have edited ..lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php and changed every logging thing I've found to false  (I wasn't sure of the logquerytime, but changing it didn't seem to change anything)

```
 protected $_debug               = false;
 protected $_logQueryTime        = 0.05;
 protected $_logAllQueries       = false;
 protected $_logCallStack        = false;
```

Is there another configuration option that I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a cron started while you had those values on true and it still is working

Comment: Who's crontab should I look at?  The user running apache?

Comment: I think so. I'm kind of illiterate when it comes to server configs and stuff.

Comment: I'll check.  Think a server reboot would help things?

Comment: Negative....www user doesn't have a crontab and reboot didn't help.

Comment: then APC, or other cacheing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by APC.  Unfortunately I have very little experience with Magento...I've just been told to fix the performance issue.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Magento doesn't log to sql.txt, but to var/log/pdo_mysql.log by default. Maybe some other code logging SQL stuff, too? Already scanned the code for sql.txt occurences? Or maybe someone configured the MySQL Server to permanently log to sql.txt?

Comment: Here's why I think it's part of this file.  If I look in the file mentioned above, I see this line

  * Path to SQL debug data log
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_debugFile           = '/usr/local/www/apache22/data/var/debug/sql.txt';